# How to create a collection of unique values based on existing array values

Tags: scala

Below code prints an Array of fileNames.

```
  val pdfFileArray = getFiles()
  for(fileName <- pdfFileArray){
    println(fileName)
  }
```

I'm trying to convert this Array (pdfFileArray) into an array which contains unique file name extensions.

Is something like below the correct way of doing this in scala ?

```
  Set<String> fileNameSet = new HashSet<String>
  val pdfFileArray = getFiles()
  for(fileName <- pdfFileArray){
    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    fileNameSet.add(extension)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
val fileNameSet = pdfFileArray.groupBy(_.split('.').last).keys
```

This assumes that all you filenames will have an extension and you only want the last extension. i.e. something.html.erb has the extension 'erb'

Comment: thanks but I think your code needs to be amended slightly : pdfFileArray.groupBy(_.getName().split('.').last).keys

Answer (score 2):

This will properly handle files with no extension (by ignoring them)

```
val extensions = getFiles().map{_.split('.').tail.lastOption}.flatten.distinct
```

so

```
Array("foo.jpg", "bar.jpg", "baz.png", "foobar")
```

becomes

```
Array("jpg", "png")
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work. `split` returns an array of one element (the whole string) if it doesn't find the separator. So lastOption will always be a Some. That means you'd get Array("jpg", "png", "foobar")

Comment: ah you're right, however `.tail.lastOption` does work, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Dan, better to use `flatMap`: `files.flatMap(_.split('.').tail.lastOption).distinct`

Answer (score 1):

There's a method in scala's collection called `distinct`, which takes away all duplicate entries in the collection. So for instance:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2).distinct
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That will give you distinct by whole filenames, how about extensions?

Comment: Map the array by taking the extensions and then distinct: ``array.map(_.lastIndexOf('.')).distinct``.

Answer (score 1):

For a sake of completeness:

```
List("foo.jpg", "bar.jpg").map(_.takeRight(3)).toSet
```

Here I'm assuming that all extensions are 3 chars long. Conversion to Set, just like .distinct method (which uses mutable set underneath, by the way) in other answers gives you unique items.

Comment: why does it matter if Set "uses mutable set underneath" ?

Comment: @user470184, well, this part actually relates to .distinct, not Set, sorry, if I confused you

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with regex, which gives a more general solution because you can redefine the expression to match anything you want:

```
val R = """.*\.(.+)""".r
getFiles.collect{ case R(x) => x }.distinct
```