# How to remove duplicates From an Array in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala How can I remove Duplicates from an array. without using Distict keyword.

I have Array Like this

```
Input 

Array(1,2,3,1,3)
=====================
```

I need output like This

```
OutPut
====================
Array(1,2,3)
```

My code is

```
Val ar=Array(1,2,3,4,5)
for(i<-0  to ar.length-1){
if(ar(i)!=for())..?
```

I want to write a program without using Set And List

```
val dup =ar.foldLeft(Array[Int]()){(a,b)=>if(a contains(b)) a else a :+ b}
```

I got this solution but how it works

can any one please explain how background it works
I tried

```
1,2,3,1,2
1==2 false .. else 1 :
```

Comment: duplicate of [In Scala how do I remove duplicates from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135627/in-scala-how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a collection of unique values based on existing array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923008/how-to-create-a-collection-of-unique-values-based-on-existing-array-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very inefficient algorithm. It doesn't use `distinct`, `Set`, or `groupBy`.

```
Array(1,2,3,1,3).foldLeft(Array[Int]()){ (acc,elem) =>
  if (acc.contains(elem)) acc else acc :+ elem
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working

Comment: what does :+ do here

Comment: `acc :+ elem` creates a copy of `acc` with the element `elem` appended.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit arbitrary to not want to use `.distinct`. But you could always turn it into a set and back.

```
Array(1,2,3,1,3).toSet.toArray 
res2: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Nope I know this Way But I need core

Comment: Without using Set and GroupBy without using Methods and Set and List

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with having your unique Array in sorted order, you can sort your original array, and only keep elements that are not equal to their neighbors:

```
object MyOjbect {

def makeUnique(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = { 
    if (a.isEmpty) return Array()

    a.head +: a.sorted.sliding(2).foldLeft(Array[Int]()) { (acc, ele) =>
                   if (ele(0) != ele(1)) acc :+ ele(1) else acc 
                   }
}   

def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println(makeUnique(Array(1,2,3,1,3)).toList) 
    println(makeUnique(Array(1,1,1,1,1)).toList)
    println(makeUnique(Array()).toList)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
List(1, 2, 3)
List(1)
List()
```

Comment: What :+ will do

Comment: what does :+ do exactly

Comment: @Ravi, `:+` creates a new `Array`, for example: `val b = Array(1,2,3) :+ 4` will create a new `Array` `b`, whose contents are: `Array(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: But I have used for List as well ya its working
 val l=List(1,2,3,1,2).foldLeft(List[Int]()){(a,b)=>if(a contains(b)) a else a :+ b}.foreach(println(_))

Comment: @Ravi, Yes, `:+` is a method on scala collections (`Array`, `List`, `Seq`, `Vector` maybe more), so it works on all of them; it creates a new collection including a new variable, like in example I gave above.